# proof of the smallest, biggest and a generated σ-Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

I 've got following definitions:

$A=\{1,2,3\}$ , $a\in \mathbb{R} \backslash A$ and $\Omega=A \cup a$.
Now I've got to give a) the smallest $\sigma$-algebra
, b) the biggest $\sigma$-algebra and c)  a generated $\sigma$-algebra by $\{A,\{2\}\}$ over $\Omega$.
These are my solutions.

a) should be  $\{\emptyset , \{1,2,3,a\}\}$

b) sould be the power set: $\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\},\{a\},\{1,2,3\} , \{2,3,a\}, \{1,3,a\}, \{1,2,a\}, \{1,2\}, \{3,a\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,a\},\{1,3\},\{2,a\}\}$

c) should be $\{\Omega, \emptyset,\{1,2,3\}, \{a\}, \{2\}, \{1,3,a \}, \{2,a\}, \{1,3\} \}$

Anyone can check these results? I hope they are right.

Comment: Yeah, looks ok.

Comment: $\Omega$ is $A\cup\{a\}$, not $A\cup a$, but otherwise it looks okay.